# C++ Send Return SOCKET_ERROR

Tags: c++, networking, send

In my C++ application I'm using network connection (TCP).
when I'm identify a network connection error I'm trying to connect to another interface.
in the reconnection the connect function has passed with no error but on send function it return an SOCKET_ERROR and WSGetLastError return 10054.
do you know what is the meaning of this error and what should I do to resolve it?

10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10054 (connection reset by peer) after successfull connect() means that the server accepts incoming connection but after that it closes the accepted socket without waiting for incoming information. The only way to resolve this is to check the server application logic.

Answer (score 2):

`10054` means [connection reset by peer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- the remote endpoint replied with an `RST` packet to tell you that the connection isn't open. Reconnect with `connect()` instead of trying to simply change interfaces on your local end.

Comment: that's what I did. I reconnect with connect function and that function passed but in senf function after it I get the error above

Comment: Does the remote peer have the socket open again yet? Are you trying to `connect()` to a listening socket or trying to connect to a "connected" socket on the remote peer?